# Realtime concurrent Haskell MIDI buffer

Tags: multithreading, haskell, functional-programming, producer-consumer, state

### Problem Background

MIDI is a serial representation of control signals to a sound generator.  Typically, a noteOn message initiates the attack phase of a sound at a given pitch.  The note will continue through decay and sustain phases until later, a noteOff message initiates a release phase to terminate the sound.  Because of the serial representation, multiple noteOns may be sent at a single pitch with no interleaved noteOffs; typically each will simultaneously terminate (initiate the release phase of) the previous sound and trigger the initiation (attack) of a new sound, perhaps with updated parameters (namely velocity, MIDI's intensity parameter). A single noteOff will then terminate that last, most recently initiated, sound.

That makes sense when physical keys are triggering MIDI events, but in a context where an algorithm generates the notes, a different semantics may be preferred.  For example, overlapping notes at a single pitch could be matched to their own noteOffs, so that a single noteOff will not terminate previously playing notes that have not yet finished. There are many sensible semantics of how overlapping notes could be interpreted -- overlapping quiet notes could "sum" to a louder note, the loudest note could win, etc. Similarly, when an overlapping note terminates and we want to restore a "background" note, there are many sensible choices -- retrigger the background note with its original parameters, continue the overlapping note (in order to prevent an undesired attack phase) perhaps with updated parameters, etc.

I am writing a MIDI buffer to handle these possibilities. It also allows messages to be generated asynchronously out of order, so each is stored with a timestamp until it is time to actually emit it.

### My Solution

MIDI events are produced and consumed in separate threads, each `ReaderT (MVar`[Heap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/heap-1.0.4/docs/Data-Heap.html#t:Heap)`)` where Heap is a priority queue ordered by the timestamps. The producer decorates noteOn/noteOff pairs with a matching unique id `uid` so they can be reassociated in the event of overlap.

So far so good, but the consumer turns out to be relatively convoluted, and smells too imperative. I suspect there is a more functional approach that would simplify it.  It `whileM`s until the queue is empty, `threadDelay`s until the timestamp of the most imminent event, and then has to maintain state representing the overlap structure of currently playing notes. I chose `StateT (`[IntMap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-IntMap-Lazy.html#t:IntMap)`(`[Seq](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Sequence.html#t:Seq)`(uid, velocity)))`, where the `IntMap` key is the MIDI note number and channel, identifying a unique location where notes could potentially overlap.

- noteOns are prepended onto the `Seq` as the most recent currently playing note.
- noteOffs have to find their matching uid in the `Seq`;

  - If it was the only event, it can be emitted unmodified.
  - If the match was not the current head of the `Seq`, it is suppressed, since it is a noteOff for a note that was superseded by a subsequent note that has not yet finished.
  - If the noteOff does match the current head and the tail is not empty, it is replaced by a noteOn with the velocity from the next item in the `Seq`, the next most recently initiated note.

This implements an example of the overlapping semantics I described above, but the code is hardly pleasing. All the data structures are functional, but it still feels very procedural. I don't see a way to work on this kind of problem without lots of state manipulation. I know I could break this into smaller functions, but there aren't any opportunities for reuse and it wouldn't even get me out of `IO` because I have to be working in the `MVar`.

```
drain :: KeyStateT (CtxtRdrT IO) Bool
drain = do
  s <- asks stream
  t <- liftIO time

  let cleanup nq del next = return (nq, (next, del, H.null nq))
  (next, del, out) <- lift . asksTo modifyMVar queue $ \q ->
    (flip $ maybe (cleanup q False Nothing)) (H.view q) $ \(next, rest) -> do
      e <- liftIO $ useStream s "existing error" hasHostError
      if timestamp (evt next) <= myLatMS + t || fromMaybe True e
        then cleanup rest False $ Just next
        else cleanup q    True    Nothing

  let evtNext = evt <$> next

  new <- flip (maybe $ return evtNext) -- nothing in queue or not time yet
    (decodeMsg . message <$> evtNext) $ \msg ->
      let vel = fromIntegral . data2 $ msg
          u   = uid . fromJust $ next
          uv  = (u, vel)
          chanXkey
            = (1 + fromIntegral (maxBound :: Word8))
            * (fromIntegral . status $ msg)
            + (fromIntegral . data1  $ msg)
      in {- (liftIO . print =<<) . -} (StateT $ getCompose . (`I.alterF` chanXkey) (Compose <$>
           if vel == 0 -- can't figure out how to factor out the `return` from all clauses below
             then maybe (error "too many noteOffs") $ \xs -> do
               let (pre, match :<| post) = S.breakl ((== u) . fst) xs
                   rest                  = pre >< post
               liftIO $ putStrLn $ "match: " ++ show match
               if S.null rest
                 then return (evtNext, Nothing) -- noteOff for currently playing note
                 else do
                   let next' = if S.null pre
                         then (\x -> x {message = encodeMsg $ msg {data2 = fromIntegral $ snd hd}}) 
                                <$> evtNext
                         else Nothing -- later note still playing
                         where hd :<| _ = post
                   liftIO $ putStrLn $ "next: " ++ show next'
                   return (next', Just rest)
             else return . (evtNext, ) . Just . maybe (S.singleton uv) (uv <|)))
         <* (liftIO . putStrLn . showTree =<< get)

  (`traverse_` new) $ liftIO . useStream s "checking for new errors (writeEvents)"
    . ((doError "writing events" =<<) .) . (flip writeEvents . return)

  when del . liftIO . pauseSec $ toRational myLatMS / 1000
  return $ not out
```

Here's a complete running example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances      #-}

module MidiBuffer
  ( midiBuffer
  ) where

-- heap on hackage
import qualified Data.Heap                  as H
-- also consider "heaps"    http://hackage.haskell.org/package/heaps
-- and           "psqueues" http://hackage.haskell.org/package/psqueues

-- PortMidi on hackage
import           Sound.PortMidi

-- extra on hackage
import           Control.Monad.Extra        hiding (unit)

import           Control.Concurrent
import           Control.Exception.Base
import           Control.Arrow
import           Control.Monad.Reader
import           Control.Monad.State
import           Data.Functor.Compose

import           Data.Foldable
import           Data.Maybe
import           Data.Tuple
import           Data.Word
import           Numeric.Natural

-- containers on hackage
import qualified Data.IntMap.Lazy           as I
import           Data.IntMap.Internal.Debug
import           Data.Sequence              (Seq (..), (<|), (><))
import qualified Data.Sequence              as S

midiBuffer :: IO ()
midiBuffer = do
  doError "initializing" =<< initialize

  n <- showResult (("found " ++) . (++ " devices")) countDevices
  traverse_
    (\x ->
       putStrLn . (("device " ++ show x ++ ": ") ++) . show =<< getDeviceInfo x)
    [0 .. n - 1]

  d <- getDefaultOutputDeviceID
  putStrLn $ "default output is " ++ show d

  s <- traverse (`openOutput` latencyMS) d
  let t = "opening stream"
      u = useStream s
  u t $ (False <$) . putStrLn . ((t ++ ": ") ++) . show

  t <- time -- must be evaluated after opening stream, which resets the counter!  portmidi.h says:
  -- "If the application wants to use PortTime, it should start the timer (call Pt_Start) before calling Pm_OpenInput or Pm_OpenOutput."
  -- but PortMidi.hs neither exposes Pt_Start nor calls it

  q <- newMVar (H.empty :: PMQ)
  let withContext = flip runReaderT Context 
        { queue     = q
        , startTime = fromIntegral t
        , stream    = s
        }

      chan  = 0
      base  = 60
      ns    = [1 .. 4]
      notes = zipWith3
          note
          (replicate (length ns) base)
          (fromIntegral . (20 +) . (25 *) <$> ns)
          ns
      notes' = zipWith
          (\x y -> changeDur x {measure = 1} y)
          notes
          [Whole, Half, Eighth, Eighth]

      run :: s -> StateT s (CtxtRdrT IO) a -> IO ()
--    run :: (MonadReader Context m, MonadState s m, MonadIO m) => s -> m a -> IO () -- why won't this work?      
      run x = withContext . void . (`runStateT` x)

  void . (`forkFinally` putStrLn . (displayException ||| const "producer: clean exit")) 
       . run 0 $ traverse_ addNote (notes ++ notes')

  whileM $ H.null <$> readMVar q -- funny bug if you forget ($)
  run I.empty $ whileM drain

  u "checking for new errors (hasHostError)"
    $ (`when'` putStrLn "\n***PortMidi host error") <=< hasHostError
  -- PortMidi.hs doesn't expose Pm_GetHostErrorText()

  u "checking for new errors (close)" $ (doError "closing stream" =<<) . close

  void . doError "terminating" =<< terminate

note n v b = Note
  { midiNum = n
  , vel     = v
  , chan    = 0
  , measure = 0
  , beat    = b
  , subdiv  = 0
  , dur     = Whole
  }

when'
  :: Applicative m
  => Bool -> m () -> m Bool
when' p = (p <$) . when p

-- * configuration
latencyMS = 1 -- must be > 0, or portmidi ignores timestamps
myLatMS   = 1 -- the latency of our scheduler (events need to be added this far ahead of time in order to be output in order, otherwise they will just be emitted immediately)
tempo     = 200 -- bpm
timeSig   = TimeSig {numBeats = 4, unit = Quarter}

-- * music util
data DurBase
  = Whole
  | Half
  | Quarter
  | Eighth
  | Sixteenth
  | ThirtySecond
  deriving (Enum, Bounded, Show, Eq)

data ModDur
  = forall x. NoteDur x => Dotted x
  | Triplet DurBase

data TimeSig = TimeSig
  { numBeats :: Int
  , unit     :: DurBase
  }

data Note = forall x. NoteDur x => Note
  { midiNum :: Word8
  , vel     :: Word8
  , chan    :: Word8
  , measure :: forall a. Integral a => a -- new ghc: no longer compiles without forall a here...  why?
  , beat    :: Int
  , subdiv  :: forall a. (Real a, Fractional a) => a -- % of beat -- new ghc: no longer compiles without forall a here...  why?
  , dur     :: x
  }

instance Show Note where
  show n = show (midiNum n, vel n)

-- http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12-latest/html/users_guide/release-6-12-1.html#id2887987
-- Record updates can now be used with datatypes containing existential type variables, provided the fields being altered do not mention the existential types.
changeDur
  :: (NoteDur b)
  => Note -> b -> Note -- would rather use existential record update syntax, but dur is existential
changeDur Note {..} d =
  Note {midiNum, vel, chan, measure, beat, subdiv, dur = d}

class NoteDur a where
  quarters
    :: (Real x, Fractional x)
    => a -> x

  durMS
    :: (Real x, Fractional x)
    => a -> x
  durMS d = 1000 * 60 * beats d / realToFrac tempo

  beats
    :: (Real x, Fractional x)
    => a -> x
  beats d = uncurry (/) $ both quarters (d, unit timeSig)
    where
      both (f :: forall a b. (NoteDur a, Real b, Fractional b) => a -> b) 
           (x, y) = (f x, f y) -- lame that this has to be class specific (copumpkin @ #haskell says a 'forall classes' would be nice)
--    beats d = (quarters d) / (quarters $ unit timeSig) -- want to factor out the application of quarters
--    beats d = uncurry (/) $ join (***) quarters (d, unit timeSig) -- join (***) from Saizan_ @ #haskell, but isn't existentially polymorphic

instance NoteDur DurBase where
  quarters x = fromJust . lookup x . zip [minBound .. maxBound] $
    map (fromRational . (2 ^^)) [2,1 ..]

instance NoteDur ModDur where
  quarters (Dotted  x) = quarters x * 3 / 2
  quarters (Triplet x) = quarters x * 2 / 3
{- why isn't something like this OK?  scree @ #haskell points out that if NoteDur were a type instead of a class it would work, but then we have to carry around another constructor (ie: NoteDur Dotted Eighth)
    quarters (x y) = quarters y * case x of
        Dotted  -> 3 / 2
        Triplet -> 2 / 3
-}

instance NoteDur Note where
  quarters Note {..} = quarters dur

startMS
  :: (Real a, Fractional a)
  => Note -> a
startMS n
  = realToFrac (subdiv n + fromIntegral ((measure n * numBeats timeSig) + beat n))
  * durMS (unit timeSig)

-- * our scheduler ensures we send monotonic increasing timestamps to portmidi
-- igel @ #haskell (Data.Heap's author) agrees there's no way to reuse MinPolicy here -- HeapItem MinPolicy a is already defined for all a
-- edward says it might have been possible for him to use a class that would let us override it
data PMPol

instance H.HeapItem PMPol QEvent where
  newtype Prio PMPol QEvent = PMP (Integer, Integer)
                          deriving (Eq, Ord)

  type Val PMPol QEvent = QEvent

  split = PMP -- velocity is 2nd component of ordering so noteoffs happen before noteons
    . (fromIntegral . timestamp &&& fromIntegral . data2 . decodeMsg . message) . evt
    &&& id

  merge = snd

type PMQ = H.Heap PMPol QEvent

data QEvent = QEvent
  { evt :: PMEvent
  , uid :: Natural
  }

instance Show QEvent where 
  show = show . uid

-- in midi, a noteOff at a given midi number turns off that note no matter how many previous noteOns occurred
-- so previously scheduled noteOffs might prematurely cut off any new note
-- or a new note may prematurely cut off previously scheduled notes
-- also new notes permanently overwrite previously playing notes' velocities at that midi number
-- we fix this by keeping track of currently playing notes and their future noteOffs
addNote :: Note -> IdStateT (CtxtRdrT IO) ()
addNote n = do
  t   <- asks startTime
  uid <- state $ id &&& (+ 1) -- does this occur even if uid never needed (ex: zero dur event)?
  let start  = PMEvent {message = encodeMsg noteOn , timestamp = startT}
      end    = PMEvent {message = encodeMsg noteOff, timestamp = endT  }
      startT = t      + round (startMS n)
      endT   = startT + round (durMS   n)
      noteOn = PMMsg
        { status = fromIntegral $ onCode + chan n
        , data1  = fromIntegral $ midiNum n
        , data2  = fromIntegral $ vel     n
        }
      noteOff = noteOn {data2 = 0}
      onCode  = 0x90
  lift $ when (startT < endT) $ asksTo modifyMVar_ queue $ \q -> do
      liftIO . putStrLn $ "uid: " ++ show uid
      return . foldr H.insert q $ (\evt -> QEvent {uid, evt}) <$> [start, end] -- triggers bad hlint suggestion of const QEvent{uid,evt}

drain :: KeyStateT (CtxtRdrT IO) Bool
drain = do
  s <- asks stream
  t <- liftIO time

  let cleanup nq del next = return (nq, (next, del, H.null nq))
  (next, del, out) <- lift . asksTo modifyMVar queue $ \q ->
    (flip $ maybe (cleanup q False Nothing)) (H.view q) $ \(next, rest) -> do
      e <- liftIO $ useStream s "existing error" hasHostError
      if timestamp (evt next) <= myLatMS + t || fromMaybe True e
        then cleanup rest False $ Just next
        else cleanup q    True    Nothing

  let evtNext = evt <$> next

  new <- flip (maybe $ return evtNext) -- nothing in queue or not time yet
    (decodeMsg . message <$> evtNext) $ \msg ->
      let vel = fromIntegral . data2 $ msg
          u   = uid . fromJust $ next
          uv  = (u, vel)
          chanXkey
            = (1 + fromIntegral (maxBound :: Word8))
            * (fromIntegral . status $ msg)
            + (fromIntegral . data1  $ msg)
      in {- (liftIO . print =<<) . -} (StateT $ getCompose . (`I.alterF` chanXkey) (Compose <$>
           if vel == 0 -- can't figure out how to factor out the `return` from all clauses below
             then maybe (error "too many noteOffs") $ \xs -> do
               let (pre, match :<| post) = S.breakl ((== u) . fst) xs
                   rest                  = pre >< post
               liftIO $ putStrLn $ "match: " ++ show match
               if S.null rest
                 then return (evtNext, Nothing) -- noteOff for currently playing note
                 else do
                   let next' = if S.null pre
                         then (\x -> x {message = encodeMsg $ msg {data2 = fromIntegral $ snd hd}}) 
                                <$> evtNext
                         else Nothing -- later note still playing
                         where hd :<| _ = post
                   liftIO $ putStrLn $ "next: " ++ show next'
                   return (next', Just rest)
             else return . (evtNext, ) . Just . maybe (S.singleton uv) (uv <|)))
         <* (liftIO . putStrLn . showTree =<< get)

  (`traverse_` new) $ liftIO . useStream s "checking for new errors (writeEvents)"
    . ((doError "writing events" =<<) .) . (flip writeEvents . return)

  when del . liftIO . pauseSec $ toRational myLatMS / 1000
  return $ not out

data Context = Context
  { queue     :: MVar PMQ
  , startTime :: forall a. Real a => a -- new ghc: no longer compiles without forall a here...  why?
  , stream    :: Maybe (Either PMStream PMError)
  }

type IdStateT  = StateT Natural
type CtxtRdrT  = ReaderT Context
type KeyStateT = StateT Keys
type Keys      = I.IntMap (Seq (Natural, Word8))

-- * general util

pauseSec
  :: Real a
  => a -> IO ()
pauseSec = threadDelay . round . (* 1000000) . realToFrac -- threadDealy's resolution looks to be 10ms, seems very large?  (seems ~2x better in 6.12?)

-- from ski @ #haskell (see http://tunes.org/~nef//logs/haskell/09.08.06)
-- solution to this problem: lpaste.net/7915
-- avoids nesting liftIO's, which gives a compiler error, when one wants more than one MVar from a ReaderT simultaneously using form:
-- asks selector >>= liftIO . (flip xxxMVar) (\x ->
-- it's still not as polymorphic as we'd like -- it only works for ReaderT's instead of all MonadReader's
-- why not allow nested liftIO's, and if there is a good reason, is there a more general solution than asksTo?
-- does MonadIO do it?
-- ski mentioned this is "monad tunneling" but i can't find other references to that term...
asksTo
  :: Monad m
  => (a -> (b -> m1 c) -> m d) -- modifyMVar :: MVar a -> (a -> IO (a, b)) -> IO b
  -> (r -> a)
  -> (b -> ReaderT r m1 c)
  -> ReaderT r m d
asksTo wrap sel body = do
  mv <- asks sel
  ReaderT $ \r -> wrap mv $ (`runReaderT` r) . body

showResult
  :: Show a
  => (String -> String) -> IO a -> IO a
showResult g f = do
  x <- f
  putStrLn . g $ show x
  return x

doError :: String -> PMError -> IO Bool
doError s e = do
  putStr $ s ++ "... " ++ show e
  let b = e /= NoError
  when b . putStr . (": " ++) =<< getErrorText e
  putStrLn ""
  return b

useStream
  :: Traversable t
  => t (Either a PMError) 
  -> String 
  -> (a -> IO Bool) 
  -> IO (t Bool)
useStream s b a = traverse (a ||| doError b) s
```

Comment: You'll need to set something up to receive the MIDI, like [SimpleSynth](http://notahat.com/simplesynth/).  Including this in the question flagged it as spam :(